Read variables saved in react-native by Kotlin native code (broadcastReceiver)
So guys I have a problem and I need help. I made a class in my application that has a BroadcastReceiver and its objective is to check if the user pressed the "Power" button on the cell phone and if he presses it following the rules, the code makes an HTTP request. I did this to trigger a request even if the application is closed or in the background. What I need now is to define the control variables within the BroadcastReceiver through react-native. Ex: If the user does not want the request, I will place a control variable to stop the request, or the user can choose how many times the "POWER" button will be pressed; Can anyone help me with how to make this bridge and be able to read variables saved in react-native by native Kotlin code?
PowerButtonReceiver.kt
package com.williamlima300.backgroundtest

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.SystemClock
import androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager
import androidx.work.OneTimeWorkRequest
import androidx.work.WorkManager
import androidx.work.Worker
import androidx.work.WorkerParameters
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.Request
import java.io.IOException

class PowerButtonReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
  companion object {
    var powerPressCount = 0
    var lastPowerPressTime: Long = 0
  }

  override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
    if (intent?.action == Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF || intent?.action == Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON) {
      val currentTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
      if (currentTime - lastPowerPressTime < 1000) {
        powerPressCount++
      } else {
        powerPressCount = 1
      }
      lastPowerPressTime = currentTime

      if (powerPressCount == 3) {
        // Envia um broadcast local para comunicar com o React Native
        val localIntent = Intent("POWER_BUTTON_PRESSED")
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context!!).sendBroadcast(localIntent)

        // Enfileira uma tarefa para o WorkManager
        val workRequest = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(HttpRequestWorker::class.java).build()
        WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueue(workRequest)

        powerPressCount = 0
      }
    }
  }
}

class HttpRequestWorker(context: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) : Worker(context, workerParams) {
  override fun doWork(): Result {
    val client = OkHttpClient()
    val request = Request.Builder()
      .url("https://4591-2804-15b4-203-1c95-4457-404-d9e2-f3c6.ngrok-free.app/testeBackground")
      .build()

    return try {
      val response = client.newCall(request).execute()
      if (response.isSuccessful) {
        Result.success()
      } else {
        Result.failure()
      }
    } catch (e: IOException) {
      e.printStackTrace()
      Result.retry()
    }
  }
}


MainActivity.kt
package com.williamlima300.backgroundtest

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.IntentFilter
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.fabricEnabled
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultReactActivityDelegate
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.DeviceEventManagerModule
import expo.modules.ReactActivityDelegateWrapper

class MainActivity : ReactActivity() {
  private lateinit var powerButtonReceiver: PowerButtonReceiver

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    // Set the theme to AppTheme BEFORE onCreate to support
    // coloring the background, status bar, and navigation bar.
    // This is required for expo-splash-screen.
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme)
    super.onCreate(null)

    // Register the PowerButtonReceiver
    val filter = IntentFilter()
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)
    powerButtonReceiver = PowerButtonReceiver()
    registerReceiver(powerButtonReceiver, filter)

    // Register the local broadcast receiver
    val localBroadcastReceiver = LocalBroadcastReceiver()
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(localBroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter("POWER_BUTTON_PRESSED"))
  }

  override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    unregisterReceiver(powerButtonReceiver)
  }

  override fun getMainComponentName(): String = "main"

  override fun createReactActivityDelegate(): ReactActivityDelegate {
    return ReactActivityDelegateWrapper(
          this,
          BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED,
          object : DefaultReactActivityDelegate(
              this,
              mainComponentName,
              fabricEnabled
          ) {})
  }

  override fun invokeDefaultOnBackPressed() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
      if (!moveTaskToBack(false)) {
        super.invokeDefaultOnBackPressed()
      }
      return
    }
    super.invokeDefaultOnBackPressed()
  }

  inner class LocalBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
      val reactInstanceManager = reactNativeHost.reactInstanceManager
      val reactContext = reactInstanceManager.currentReactContext
      reactContext?.getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter::class.java)
          ?.emit("powerButtonPressed", null)
    }
  }
}


Escolha.jsx
import { useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { View, Text, Switch, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { RadioButton } from "react-native-paper";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { UserContext } from "../context/userProvider";

const Escolha = () => {
  const {
    userToken,
    isReceiverActive,
    setIsReceiverActive,
    totalCount,
    setTotalCount,
  } = useContext(UserContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem("totalCount").then((value) => {
      if (value) {
        setTotalCount(parseInt(value));
      }
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.setItem("totalCount", totalCount.toString());
    console.log("totalCount", totalCount);
  }, [totalCount]);

  useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.setItem("isReceiverActive", isReceiverActive.toString());
    console.log("isReceiverActive", isReceiverActive);
  }, [isReceiverActive]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (userToken) {
      AsyncStorage.setItem("userToken", userToken);
    }
    console.log("userToken", userToken);
  }, [userToken]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>Configurações do Broadcast Receiver</Text>
      <View style={styles.row}>
        <Text>Ativar Broadcast:</Text>
        <Switch
          value={isReceiverActive}
          onValueChange={(value) => {
            setIsReceiverActive(value);
          }}
        />
      </View>
      <Text style={styles.subtitle}>Contagem de Pressionamentos:</Text>
      <View style={styles.row}>
        {[3, 4, 5].map((count) => (
          <View key={count} style={styles.radioContainer}>
            <RadioButton
              value={count}
              status={totalCount === count ? "checked" : "unchecked"}
              onPress={() => {
                setTotalCount(count);
              }}
            />
            <Text>{count}</Text>
          </View>
        ))}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 20,
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 24,
    marginBottom: 20,
    textAlign: "center",
  },
  subtitle: {
    fontSize: 18,
    marginVertical: 10,
  },
  row: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginVertical: 10,
  },
  radioContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginHorizontal: 10,
  },
});

export default Escolha;


I already tried to find solutions using AsyncStorage and NativeModules but I was unsuccessful
